# git statusでcopiedとなる操作は？

Tags: git

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status
上記公式ドキュメントのヘルプに記載されている、git status -sで表示されるc(copied)というステータスはどんな操作をした時に発生するものでしょうか？

ファイルを複製すると発生するのかと思い、
以下操作をしてみましたが発生しませんでした。
1.file1を作成(中身は適当)
2.git add file1
3.git commit file1 -m 'test'
4.file1をコピーしてfile2を作成
5.git add file2
6.git status -s

file2はfaile1のコピーなのでC(copied)となるかと思いましたがA(added)という判定になりました。

Comment: [英語版SOの同様の質問](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27251403/4506703)では`git-status` でコピーは検出できない、ドキュメントの誤記だ、とありますね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[英語版SOの同様の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198414/git-status-git-diff-c-not-detecting-file-copy-in-index/27251403#27251403)ではgit-status でコピーは検出できない、ドキュメントの誤記という事をコメントにて教えて頂きました。

大変助かりました、ありがとうございます。